# java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object android error?

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

This part of the code deals with creating preferences programatically and also handle related actions.
I can't understand what the problem is.

This is my code

```
package za.co.neilson.alarm.preferences;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import za.co.neilson.alarm.Alarm;
import za.co.neilson.alarm.preferences.AlarmPreference.Type;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AlarmPreferenceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Serializable {

//it has all the preferences defined here

private Context context;
private Alarm alarm;
private List<AlarmPreference> preferences = new ArrayList<AlarmPreference>();
private final String[] repeatDays = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};   
private final String[] actions = {"Switch On", "Switch Off"};
private String[] alarmTones;
private String[] alarmTonePaths;

public AlarmPreferenceListAdapter(Context context, Alarm alarm) {
    setContext(context);


//      (new Runnable(){
//
//          @Override
//          public void run() {
            Log.d("AlarmPreferenceListAdapter", "Loading Ringtones...");

            RingtoneManager ringtoneMgr = new RingtoneManager(getContext());

            ringtoneMgr.setType(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

            Cursor alarmsCursor = ringtoneMgr.getCursor();

            alarmTones = new String[alarmsCursor.getCount()+1];
            alarmTones[0] = "Silent"; 
            alarmTonePaths = new String[alarmsCursor.getCount()+1];
            alarmTonePaths[0] = "";

            if (alarmsCursor.moveToFirst()) {                       
                do {
                    alarmTones[alarmsCursor.getPosition()+1] = ringtoneMgr.getRingtone(alarmsCursor.getPosition()).getTitle(getContext());
                    alarmTonePaths[alarmsCursor.getPosition()+1] = ringtoneMgr.getRingtoneUri(alarmsCursor.getPosition()).toString();
                }while(alarmsCursor.moveToNext());                  
            }
            //Log.d("AlarmPreferenceListAdapter", "Finished Loading " + alarmTones.length + " Ringtones.");
            alarmsCursor.close();
//              
//          }
//          
//      }).run();
//      
    setMathAlarm(alarm);        
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return preferences.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return preferences.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    AlarmPreference alarmPreference = (AlarmPreference) getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    switch (alarmPreference.getType()) {
    case BOOLEAN:
        if(null == convertView || convertView.getId() != android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked)
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, null);

        CheckedTextView checkedTextView = (CheckedTextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        checkedTextView.setText(alarmPreference.getTitle());
        checkedTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        checkedTextView.setChecked((Boolean) alarmPreference.getValue());
        break;
    case INTEGER:
    case STRING:
    case LIST:
    case MULTIPLE_LIST:
    case TIME:
    default:
        if(null == convertView || convertView.getId() != android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2)
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, null);

        TextView text1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        text1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        text1.setTextSize(18);
        text1.setText(alarmPreference.getTitle());

        TextView text2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        text2.setText(alarmPreference.getSummary());
        text2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        break;
    }

    return convertView;
}

public Alarm getMathAlarm() {       
    for(AlarmPreference preference : preferences){
        switch(preference.getKey()){
            case ALARM_ACTIVE:
                alarm.setAlarmActive((Boolean) preference.getValue());
                break;
            case ALARM_NAME:
                alarm.setAlarmName((String) preference.getValue());
                break;
            case ALARM_TIME:
                alarm.setAlarmTime((String) preference.getValue());
                break;
            case ALARM_TONE:
                alarm.setAlarmTonePath((String) preference.getValue());
                break;
            case ALARM_REPEAT:
                alarm.setDays((Alarm.Day[]) preference.getValue());
                break;

            case AlARM_ACTION:
                alarm.setAction((String)preference.getValue());
        }
    }

    return alarm;
}

public void setMathAlarm(Alarm alarm) {
    this.alarm = alarm;
    preferences.clear();
    preferences.add(new AlarmPreference(AlarmPreference.Key.ALARM_ACTIVE,"Active", null, null, alarm.getAlarmActive(),Type.BOOLEAN));
    preferences.add(new AlarmPreference(AlarmPreference.Key.ALARM_NAME, "Label",alarm.getAlarmName(), null, alarm.getAlarmName(), Type.STRING));
    preferences.add(new AlarmPreference(AlarmPreference.Key.ALARM_TIME, "Set time",alarm.getAlarmTimeString(), null, alarm.getAlarmTime(), Type.TIME));
    preferences.add(new AlarmPreference(AlarmPreference.Key.ALARM_REPEAT, "Repeat",alarm.getRepeatDaysString(), repeatDays, alarm.getDays(),Type.MULTIPLE_LIST));


    // for choosing action

    preferences.add(new AlarmPreference(AlarmPreference.Key.AlARM_ACTION, "Action",alarm.getAction(),actions, alarm.getAction(),Type.LIST));

    //this is for ringtone
    //we want to display On and Off options instead of ringtone list
    // and set the action in database accordingly

        Uri alarmToneUri = Uri.parse(alarm.getAlarmTonePath());
        Ringtone alarmTone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getContext(), alarmToneUri);

    if(alarmTone instanceof Ringtone && !alarm.getAlarmTonePath().equalsIgnoreCase("")){
        preferences.add(new AlarmPreference(AlarmPreference.Key.ALARM_TONE, "Ringtone", alarmTone.getTitle(getContext()),alarmTones, alarm.getAlarmTonePath(), Type.LIST));
    }else{
        preferences.add(new AlarmPreference(AlarmPreference.Key.ALARM_TONE, "Ringtone", getAlarmTones()[0],alarmTones, null, Type.LIST));
    }

    //preferences.add(new AlarmPreference(AlarmPreference.Key.ALARM_VIBRATE, "Vibrate",null, null, alarm.getVibrate(), Type.BOOLEAN));
}


public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public String[] getRepeatDays() {
    return repeatDays;
}



public String[] getAlarmTones() {
    return alarmTones;
}

public String[] getAlarmTonePaths() {
    return alarmTonePaths;
}

}
```

Adding repetition:

This part of the code deals with creating preferences programatically and also handle related actions.
I can't understand what the problem is.

This part of the code deals with creating preferences programatically and also handle related actions.
I can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: Consider reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and revising your question. You can start by adding the full stack trace and pointing, in your code, specifically where the error occurs.

Comment: I changed Serializable to Parcelable and changed the implementation accordingly and it worked. Thanks.